# How related do life forms need to be to produce hybrids?

Tags: genetics, taxonomy, hybridization

Specifically, I'm asking about infertile hybrids like ligers, mules, camas, etc. How closely related do animals need to be?

Comment: Related just enough? There probably isn't a single answer across taxa.

Comment: "The number of quantitative trait loci fixed for different alleles in different species should increase with time since speciation" ([Genetic distance between species predicts novel trait expression in their hybrids](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.1111/j.1558-5646.2008.00599.x)). I suppose that the genetic distance of hybrid parents may be larger in plants than in animals.